# Reading lines from file to list in erlang, ignoring \n

Tags: list, erlang, readfile

I need to read every line of my txt file in erlang and make a list of it.
The problem is that my list looks like this:
["line1\n","line2\n","line3"]
Every element of the list (beside the last element) has the "\n" part in it, I need it to be gone. Can you please help me?
Also i will be reading big files with it(like 200000+ lines)

Here is the code:

```
-module(test1).
-export([into_list/1]).

into_list( File ) ->
  {ok, IO} = file:open( File, [read] ),
  into_list( io:get_line(IO, ''), IO, [] ).


into_list( eof, _IO, Acc ) -> lists:reverse( Acc );
into_list( {error, _Error}, _IO, Acc ) -> lists:reverse( Acc );
into_list( Line, IO, Acc ) -> into_list( io:get_line(IO, ''), IO, [Line | Acc] ).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i found a solution working just fine

```
  readfile(FileName) ->
  {ok, Binary} = file:read_file(FileName),
  Lines = string:tokens(erlang:binary_to_list(Binary), "\n").
```

Comment: One problem with this approach is if you're reading files with 200,000+ lines, you're reading the entire file into memory, then converting it all to a list, and then creating separate lists for every single line. If you're comfortable with reading the entire file into one binary, you should consider splitting it into lines using `binary:split(Binary,<<"\n">>,[global])` instead, as that will use a lot less memory.

Answer (score 2):

The key point is to remember that *string* in Erlang are nothing more than list of integers.

So, as you are comfortable with reading the entire file as binary, you can write something like that to get back the content as a list of *string*:

```
1> {ok, Binary} = file:read_file("test.txt").
{ok,<<"aaaa\nb\nvvvvv\nxxx\n">>}
2> [binary_to_list(Bin) || Bin <- binary:split(Binary,<<"\n">>,[global])].
["aaaa","b","vvvvv","xxx",[]]
```

If you are not confortable with getting back the `[]` at the end of the list, you can use a guard clause:

```
3> [binary_to_list(Bin) || Bin <- binary:split(Binary,<<"\n">>,[global]),
                           Bin =/= << >>].    
["aaaa","b","vvvvv","xxx"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between outputs of those.

`string:tokens(erlang:binary_to_list(Binary), "\n"). ["aaaa","b","vvvvv","xxx"]`

`binary:split(Binary,<<"\n">>,[global]).
[<<"aaaa">>,<<"b">>,<<"vvvvv">>,<<"xxx">>,<<>>]`

But as Steve mentioned, second one is faster.
My question is, how to eliminate <<>> from second output ?

Comment: Add `trim` to the options.